# QuickBooks PHP Sdk "Use" Causes Fatal Error

Tags: php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I am using the SDK and _Sample files to test a simple invoice creation.

I am not using composer, so the sample tells me to do this....

```
include('../config.php');

use QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\ServiceContext;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\DataService\DataService;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\PlatformService\PlatformService;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Core\Http\Serialization\XmlObjectSerializer;
use QuickBooksOnline\API\Facades\Invoice;

$dataService = DataService::Configure(array(
       'auth_mode' => 'oauth1',
         'consumerKey' => "qyprdUSoVpIHrtBp0eDMTHGz8UXuSz",
         'consumerSecret' => "TKKBfdlU1I1GEqB9P3AZlybdC8YxW5qFSbuShkG7",
         'accessTokenKey' => "qyprdxccscoNl7KRbUJoaJQIhUvyXRzD9tNOlXn4DhRDoj4g",
         'accessTokenSecret' => "JqkHSBKzNHbqjMq0Njbcq8fjgJSpfjMvqHVWnDOW",
         'QBORealmID' => "193514464689044",
         'baseUrl' => "Development"
));
```

So i have done this on my website, but I get the following error...

> ParseError: syntax error, unexpected 'use' (T_USE)

I've literally copied the code above, into a new php file. I have successfully loaded the config.php file.

I have seen elsewhere that a "use" statement must be at the top of the file... it is!

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? If PHP isn't recognizing `use`, that's telling me that your site is running PHP 5.2 or lower.

Comment: can you also post the `../config.php` file. It might be because of an error from that file.

Comment: Is there any more code to it? `use` has to be in the outermost scope of the file. What's before `include`?

Comment: Using php 7.1, and im using the PHP SDK kit with the default config.php used by loads of people, I havent messed with it.

Comment: Nothing before the include other than the opening "<?php" , its a plain file

Comment: @Collins which line specifically does the ParseError point to?

Comment: Try doing `require_once __DIR__ . '/../config.php';` instead, you might be running into a relative path issue, and this way, you're guaranteeing that either config.php loads or the application stops (and gives you more information as to what's wrong)